# How can I prevent early popup closing when using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, azure-active-directory

I'm calling **chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow** from a background script of my Chrome extension.

This is used to get implicit user authentication with https://login.microsoftonline.com

The sign in popup appears fine allowing for user credential input. However after credentials are submitted the window is not redirected to my callback redirect uri. Instead it redirects to another page (which is some kind of corporate signin page within Microsoft Azure AD) which does not require user's action.

At this very moment the window gets closed and I get *undefined* response in launchWebAuthFlow callback function. At the same time I get console error: **Unchecked runtime.lastError: Authorization page could not be loaded.**

The same flow works fine from the browser window: after credentials provision and redirect to the corporate signin page, it's finally redirected to my redirect url (with auth token ready).

From this I conclude that launchWebAuthFlow is not waiting till redirect is done to my redirect page but closes popup prematurely.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: This window is shown automatically and it should be a protected window that's not exposed via any extension API so I don't think you can control it. What you describe looks like a bug to me. Either in Chrome's auth flow or in the site. Try reporting it on https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent too much time at this but found a workaround.

Still not sure why **launchWebAuthFlow** behaves like this. But I decided to resolve otherwise.

This double redirection happens because Microsoft auth page first requires plain e-mail address input. This allows it to decide which corporate auth page to redirect to. This happens even if it reuses the current session (cookies).

So I looked for a way to shortcut the route and give the first auth page a *hint* about what corporate page should go next. For this you have to add one more parameter to the url used by **launchWebAuthFlow**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={client-id}
&response_type=token
&login_hint=user@domain.com
&prompt=login
&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
&scope={some-scope}
```

Please note, that I had to add **prompt=login** as well. It works without it from the browser (actually even faster with alive session). However, this is needed if called from **chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow**

Hope this will help somebody in similar situation.

More details here: [Microsoft identity platform and Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)